# How to filter RDDs based on a given partition?

Tags: java, apache-spark, partitioning, rdd

Consider the following example:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Row> R = input.textFile("test").mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Row>() {
        public Tuple2<String, Row> call(String arg0) throws Exception {
            String[] parts = arg0.split(" ");
            Row r = RowFactory.create(parts[0],parts[1]);
            return new Tuple2<String, Row>(r.get(0).toString(), r);
        }}).partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(20));
```

The code above creates an RDD named `R` which is partitioned in 20 pieces by hashing on the first column of a txt file named "test".

Consider that the `test.txt` file is of the following form:

```
...
valueA1 valueB1
valueA1 valueB2
valueA1 valueB3
valueA1 valueB4
...
```

In my context, I have a known value e.g., valueA1 and I want to retrieve all the other values. It is trivial to do it by using the existing filter operation with the specified value. However, I would like to avoid this since essentially the filter operation will be performed on the whole RDD.

Assume that the hash(valueA1)=3, I would like to perform a given operation only on partition 3. More generally, I am interested in dropping/selecting specific partitions from an RDD and perform operations on them.

From the SPARK API it seems that it is not possible directly is there a workaround to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For single keys you can use `lookup` method:

```
rdd.lookup("a")

// Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 4)
```

For an efficient lookup you'll need a RDD which is partitioned, for example using `HashPartitioner` as below.

If you want to simply filter partitions containing specific keys it can be done with `mapPartitionsWithIndex`:

```
import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner

val rdd = sc.parallelize(
  Seq(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3), ("a", 4), ("b", 5)
// A particular number is used only to get a reproducible output
)).partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(8))  

val keys = Set("a", "c")
val parts = keys.map(_.## % rdd.partitions.size)

rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, iter) =>
  if (parts.contains(i)) iter.filter{ case (k, _) => keys.contains(k) }
  else Iterator()
).collect

// Array[(String, Int)] = Array((a,1), (a,4), (c,3))
```

Comment: Good, answer. I think, I prefer the mapPartitionsWithIndex option since it retains the RDD type and does not necessarily require to bring data to the driver program.

Comment: Why did you use `.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(8))`? The second param to `parallelize` could've done it for you (since HashPartitioner is the default partitioner).

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Only to get a reproducible output.

Comment: Just use `8` as the second param and you'll also get...reproducible output.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski On a second  thought it won't work without  explicit `HashPartitioner`. As far as I can tell `ParallelCollectionRDD` doesn't use `HashPartioner` and computes sliced only based on indices.

Comment: I'm missing something as I don't see why `sc.parallelize(Seq(...)).partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(8))` would be different from `sc.parallelize(Seq(...), 8)`. Could you explain?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski  Take a look at  [the `slice` method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d83c2f9f0b08d6d5d369d9fae04cdb15448e7f0d/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/ParallelCollectionRDD.scala#L117). It simply computes ranges corresponding to individual partitions. So it tells us nothing about the location of individual keys. `HashPartitioning` (or any other meaningful partitioner) creates a relationship between key and partition which can be leveraged for efficient filtering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97514/discussion-between-zero323-and-jacek-laskowski).

Comment: Great Answer! Thank You!