# Keeping an index to a list as a distributed collection - Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD[(Int, List[Int])] that has a unique integer key in every partition. Suppose that data is partitioned as

Partition 1 -> (1, List1), (2, List2)

Partition 2 -> (1, List3), (2, List4)

So when I would like to lookup for the value of index 1 I wish to have

Partition 1 -> (List1)

Partition 2 -> (List3)

But the return type should be RDD[List(Int)] not Array[List(Int)] meaning that I still want a distrubuted collection over the cluster not collected to driver program.

Currently I am using filter( case { (k, v) => k == key} ).map(_._2) but I know that this doesn't do a lookup rather it searches sequentially.

I know that there is lookup method but it returns and Array not RDD. IndexedRDD also does the same.

So is there a way to do that in Spark?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter RDDs based on a given partition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944721/how-to-filter-rdds-based-on-a-given-partition)

Comment: @zero323, so as far as I've understand what you are suggesting is; rrd.mapPartitions(it => it.toMap()(key).iterator). I think this might be the solution. The only overhead would be converting the iterator to a map. After that it would be a constant-time lookup I believe. I will try this and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `mapPartitionsWithIndex`.  You can get the partition of interest from the rdd's partitioner, and in your `(Int,Iterator)=>Iterator` function you would just return an empty iterator in cases where it wasn't the partition of interest.  For simplicity I'd probably return the passed in iterator in cases where it was the correct partition, and then just use RDD.filter afterwards to simplify the code.

The iterators being operated on here are presumably lazy, so really your function is only being applied to the partition number, not fetching results from the iterator.